# ¿Por qué cuando alguien se enfada decimos que "se rebota"?

Tags: expresiones, coloquialismos, españa

Como indica el diccionario [Rebotar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=VL2FPtQ) (undécima entrada) es sinónimo de estar enfadado o enfadarse:

> 11. tr. prnl. coloq. Esp. Alterarse, enfadarse vivamente por palabras o acciones de otro.

Es por supuesto un coloquialismo y se ve que sólo se usa en España.

> Juan está *rebotado* porque ha encontrado un arañazo en el coche.
>
> Me reboté bastante el otro día, con lo que me dijo ese señor.

Es curioso que un verbo que significa no solo "botar repetidamente" sino también "Volver a la dirección de origen; Retroceder o cambiar de dirección por haber chocado con un obstáculo" se use para estar enfadado. Recuerdo que de niño, cuando alguien decía algo para insultarte, le podías decir "Rebota rebota (que tu culo explota)". Por tanto, "me rebota" debería significar "no me afecta", pero el sentido del coloquialismo es el contrario" me afecta y me enfado.

> Esos comentarios tan machistas *me rebotan* (Me dan igual. No me afectan).
>
> Esos comentarios tan machistas *me rebotan* (Me hacen enfadar).

¿Cómo ha llegado **rebotar** a adquirir el significado de "hacer enfadar"?

Comment: Aquí de algo que no nos afecta decimos más bien "me resbala". Si algo me rebota debo haber sentido la fuerza del golpe, por aquello que decía Newton...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En Argentina se usa un verbo parecido: **retobarse,** aunque el nuestro lleva también una idea de rebelión. Resulta que se trata de una metátesis del de ustedes. La historia completa:

El origen no es **botar** sino [**boto,**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5ziiNrY|5zj9Xiw|5zjDEs8) que significa *romo* (aplicado a cosas) y *obtuso, necio* (a personas). Es la raíz de palabras como *embotado* y de las definiciones 6, 9, 10 y 11 de [**rebotar.**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=VL2FPtQ)

En el s. XIV, **rebotar** significaba *embotar*, *desteñir*, *doblar la cabeza un clavo*.

De ahí, en el s. XVI, **rebotado** adquirió el significado de *engreído*,* y en el s. XVII el de *conturbado, puesto fuera de sí*.

De aquí el **rebotarse** de la pregunta. La palabra siguió viaje; Corominas enumera algunos destinos:

- **retobarse** rioplatense, ver arriba
- **retrobar** chileno: *regañar, rezongar*
- **rebotado**

  - peruano: *taimado, camandulero*
  - ecuatoriano: *terco, porfiado, caprichoso*
  - cubano: *(persona o animal) indómito, que no respeta el ejercicio de poder de su superior*
  - centroamericano: *refunfuñador, malcriado, indómito, resabiado, repropio*
  - mexicano: *respondón, quisquilloso*

---

**Fuente:**
Corominas y Pascual. *Diccionario Crítico Etimológico Castellano e Hispánico*. Gredos, Madrid, 1984.

---

* Nota: ¿tal vez por el aspecto displicente del que tiene los sentidos embotados, parecido al del engreído? Corominas no explica este salto semántico.

Comment: En Colombia cuando alguien se rebota no es simplemente un enfado. Cuando alguien se rebota es que se enoja y demuestra abiertamente su enfado gritando y moviéndose exageradamente.

Comment: Es extraño, ninguno de los diccionario de los siglos XVI al XVIII incluidos en [el NTLLE](http://www.rae.es/recursos/diccionarios/diccionarios-anteriores-1726-1992/nuevo-tesoro-lexicografico) hace mención a la acepción de "rebotado" como "engreído" o "puesto fuera de sí". Ya entrados en el siglo XIX (1803) es cuando aparece la acepción de "rebotarse" como "cambiar de parecer". Me pregunto de dónde sacaría Corominas esa información...

Comment: @CarlosAlejo Pone como referencia a Balbuena, que supongo que es [este](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernardo_de_Balbuena), y que lo usaría con ese sentido en alguna de sus obras.