# ¿Es "sudamericano" un insulto para los mexicanos?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, hispanoamérica, insultos, gentilicio

Nótese que hago esta pregunta desde el respeto y con ánimo de aprender, y bajo ningún concepto con intención de herir a nadie.

El otro día se causó un pequeño revuelo en la pregunta [¿Qué empieza por la letra “F” y se parece a una bombilla?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/19857/12637), dado que el texto de la pregunta contiene la palabra "sudamericano", mientras que por el contexto y viendo la imagen se podía deducir que se hacía referencia al español de México.

Entendemos que es muy fácil usar la denominación "norteamérica" para hacer referencia a Estados Unidos únicamente. En España cometemos ese error con más frecuencia de la deseada, yo personalmente intento usar las denominaciones "Estados Unidos" y "estadounidense". En contraposición, es fácil caer en el término "sudamérica" para denominar al resto de países que hay desde la frontera sur de Estados Unidos hacia abajo. Entendemos también que es un error y pedimos perdón por ello, entiéndase simplemente que se dice así más por flojera o desconocimiento que por otra cosa.

Dada la circunstancia de aquella pregunta, hubo quien [se rebotó](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/19897/12637) un poco. Y para que no nos vuelva a pasar, pregunto: ¿es un insulto para un mexicano (y para los habitantes de la América Central) que se le denomine "sudamericano"?

Comment: Lo publiqué en [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/mexico/comments/5wvyy4/es_sudamericano_un_insulto_para_los_mexicanos/) y está generando bastante debate (y visitas).

Comment: @fedorqui pues ya somos dos, yo lo publiqué [esta mañana](https://www.reddit.com/r/mexico/comments/5wv9dk/con_la_mejor_de_las_intenciones_y_con_%C3%A1nimo_de/ded974u/)... :D

Comment: Yo no lo considero insulto pero es simplemente incorrecto. Soy consciente México está en Norteamérica. Sí alguien me dijera sudamericano o que México está en Sudamérica simplemente pensaría que eso está totalmente fuera de lugar y erróneo. No sé si la mayoría de mexicanos identifican a México como un país de Norteamérica o Centroamérica, pero no me cabe duda que nadie lo identifica como Sudamérica (tal vez algún despistado solamente).

Comment: Esta pregunta la iba a hacer yo esta noche. También la tenía pendiente desde la pregunta del foco/farol.

Answer (score 6):

No es insulto, pero no somos Sudamérica. De hecho, somos Norteamérica. Abajo de nosotros también está Centroamérica y ya abajo de Panamá está Sudamérica.